# Select values when column names are stored as concatenated strings

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

It's hard to explain, so I'll start with an example. I have some numeric columns (A, B, C). The column 'tmp' contains variable names of the numeric columns as concatenated strings:

```
set.seed(100)
A <- floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10))
B <- floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10))
C <- floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10))
tmp <- c('A','B,C','C','A,B','A,B,C')

df <- data.frame(A,B,C,tmp)

  A B C   tmp
1 3 4 6     A
2 2 8 8   B,C
3 5 3 2     C
4 0 5 3   A,B
5 4 1 7 A,B,C
```

Now, for each row, I want to use the variable names in `tmp` to select the values from the corresponding numeric columns with the same name(s). Then I want to keep only the rows where *all* the selected values are less than or equal 3.

E.g. in the first row, `tmp` is `A`, and the corresponding value in column `A` is 3, i.e. keep this row.

Another example, in row 4, `tmp` is `A,B`. The corresponding values are `A = 0` and `B = 5`. Thus, *all* selected values are *not* less than or equal 3, and this row is discarded.

Desired result:

```
  A B C   tmp
1 3 4 6     A
2 5 3 2     C
```

How can I perform such filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated than I like and there might be a more elegant solution, but here we go:

```
#split tmp
col <- strsplit(df[["tmp"]], ",")

#create an index matrix
inds <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, row = seq_along(col), col = col))
inds$col <- match(inds$col, names(df))
inds <- as.matrix(inds)

#check
chk <- m <- as.matrix(df[, names(df) != "tmp"])
mode(chk) <- "logical"
chk[] <- NA
chk[inds] <- m[inds] <= 3
sel <- apply(chk, 1, prod, na.rm = TRUE)

df[as.logical(sel),]
#  A B C tmp
#1 3 4 6   A
#3 5 3 2   C
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works always (and probably isn't the best solution)... but it worked here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

        List= vector("list")
    
    for (i in 1:length(df)){
      
      tmpT= as.vector(str_split(df$tmp[i], ",", simplify=TRUE))
      
      selec= df %>% 
        select(tmpT) %>%
        slice(which(row_number() == i)) %>% 
        filter_all(., all_vars(. <= 3)) %>% 
        unite(val, sep= ", ")
      
    if (nrow(selec) == 0) {
      tab= NA
    } else{ 
        tab= df[i,]
    }
      
    List[[i]] = tab
      
    }
    
    df2= do.call("rbind", List)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer has some similarities with @Roland's, but here we work with the data in a 'longer' format:

```
# create row index
df$ri = seq_len(nrow(df))

# split the concatenated column
l <- strsplit(df$tmp, ',')

# repeat each row of the data with the lengths of the split string,
# bind with individual strings
d = cbind(df[rep(1:nrow(df), lengths(l)), ], x = unlist(l))

# use match to grab values from corresponding columns
d$val <- d[cbind(seq(nrow(d)), match(d$x, names(d)))]

# for each original row 'ri', check if all values are <= 3. use result to index data frame
d[as.logical(ave(d$val, d$ri, FUN = function(x) all(x <= 3))), ]
#   A B C tmp ri x val
# 1 3 4 6   A  1 A   3
# 3 5 3 2   C  3 C   2
```